# VBA Sort with Spinners

Tags: vba, sorting, spinner

I am working on an excel spreadsheet that contains several rows worth of data that I need to sort based on the values in Column A. Column B contains values that are controlled by Spinners also located in Column B.

What I am trying to do is create buttons that when pressed will sort all of the rows based on Column A but without breaking the spinners.

What I have tried so far:

- When I just use a simple sort function, it moves the rows as required along with the spinners but it doesn't update the Cell Links on the spinners so they remain linked to the cells in the old questions.
- I tried adding in a line in the VBA for the spinners that would update the spinners Cell Link when the spinner was pressed. The problem here is that excel would first run the increment portion of the spinner before updating the link, resulting in it incrementing/decrementing the old cell before updating the link.
- I tried adding in a line in the VBA for the SORT Macros that would run a For loop to update all of the spinner Cell Links based on their new topleftcell value. This works for the Cell Link but it also updates the Cell Value based on what seems to be the Cell Value of the last spinner moved. Needless to say this is also a problem.

I'm not sure what else to try as I am still quite inexperienced with VBA.

If anyone has any suggestions for sorting cells that contain spinners without breaking the spinner's values or links I would be very appreciative!

Thanks in advance and please let me know if further information is required. I can include snippets of the code I've used so far but I wasn't sure if it owuld help much.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Sub SORT()

   Range("A2:B4").SORT. Key1:=Range("A2"), Order:=xlAscending
   Call SpinnerControl

End Sub



Sub SpinnerControl()

Dim spn As Spinner
Dim rng As Range

    For Each spn In ActiveSheet.Spinners
        Set rng = spn.TopLeftCell
        spn.LinkedCell = rng.Address(external:=False)
    Next spn

End Sub
```